# How to List pages in other pages in wordpress(Ex: wp-show-posts)

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I have a word press website where I have a list of programming language cheat sheets. Also, I have a blog where I post my articles. Now I want a list of cheat sheets on the parent page (like the blogs page). I have to show an image of the cheatsheet and a read more button. I tried using wp-show-posts plugin. But that lists all the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a certain category to all those cheat sheet posts and then use a custom query which only queries the posts which have that category. (see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/  for details)

Comment: So I need to write PHP?

Comment: Either that, or you use some plugin that can create a query by category. I think if you use Gutenberg, there are blocks that can do this (use "recent posts" / "post by category" or a similar search term)

Comment: Can you tell me some plugin. I am actually new to wordpress

Comment: This is a start for a search in the plugin directory: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/list+posts+by+category/